# Swift - UIBezierPath Extra argument 'radius' in call

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, layoutsubviews

I was adapting an Objective-C Library ([STKSpinnerView](https://github.com/stablekernel/STKSpinnerView/tree/master/Spyndle)) to Swift and I can't solve this error:

```
func getRadius() -> CGFloat {
    var r : CGRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, self.wellThickness/2.0, self.wellThickness/2.0)
    var w : CGFloat = r.size.width
    var h : CGFloat = r.size.height

    if w > h {
        return h/2.0
    }else{
        return w/2.0
    }
}

override func layoutSubviews()  {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    var bounds : CGRect = self.bounds
    var wt : CGFloat = self.wellThickness
    var outer : CGRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, wt/2.0, wt/2.0)
    var inner : CGRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, wt, wt)

    var innerPath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: inner)
    var arcCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(outer), CGRectGetMidY(outer))
    var radius = self.getRadius()
    var startAngle = -(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
    var endAngle = (2.0 * M_PI - M_PI_2)
    // (Next line) ERROR: Extra argument 'radius' in call
    var outerPath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true) 

}
```

I don't understand why 'radius' is an extra argument if I use the method like Apple say...
Do you know how to solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in the playground.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error message is very misleading. The real problem is that the `endAngle:` 
parameter of `UIBezierPath(...)` has the type `CGFloat`, but you are passing a
`Double` argument. Casting the value explicitly helps:

```
var endAngle = CGFloat(2.0 * M_PI - M_PI_2)
```

The problem occurs when compiling for the 32-bit architecture, where `CGFloat`
is defined as `Float` and not as a `Double`.

See also https://github.com/ksm/SwiftInFlux:

> What is happening here is that CGFloat is a typealias for either Float
>   or Double depending on whether you're building for 32 or 64-bits. This
>   is exactly how Objective-C works, but is problematic in Swift because
>   Swift doesn't allow implicit conversions.
>
> We're aware of this problem and consider it to be serious: we are
>   evaluating several different solutions right now and will roll one out
>   in a later beta. As you notice, you can cope with this today by
>   casting to Double. This is inelegant but effective :-)
>
> -- Chris Lattner
>
> Sources: https://devforums.apple.com/message/998222#998222

Comment: Great! Some insight by Chris Lattner. Missed his post and I really appreciate your quote!

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: I have verified it again with Xcode 6.1.1, and with my proposed change the code does compile.

Comment: @MartinR You're right. I was assigning to a variable of type CGPath, which caused an identical error. Adding a trailing `.CGPath` fixed it.